# Updating a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

I have this array which i am trying to update

```
$arr = array(
    'one' => array(
    'slidertitle' => 'lorem ipsum',
    'sliderlocation' => 'http://localhost/images/1.jpg',
    'sliderdescription' => 'this is a good lorem ipsum image',
    'sliderposition' => 1
    ),
    'two' => array(
    'slidertitle' => 'second slider',
    'sliderlocation' => 'http://localhost/images/2.jpg',
    'sliderdescription' => 'this space was reserved for a link source code here',
    'sliderposition' => 2
    ),
    'three' => array(
    'slidertitle' => 'third slider',
    'sliderlocation' => 'http://localhost/images/3.jpg',
    'sliderdescription' => 'this is a third slider by name only',
    'sliderposition' => 3
    ),
    'four' => array(
    'slidertitle' => 'fourth slider',
    'sliderlocation' => 'http://localhost/images/4.jpg',
    'sliderdescription' => 'fourth slider has a description',
    'sliderposition' => 4
    ),
    'five' => array(
    'slidertitle' => 'fifth slider',
    'sliderlocation' => 'http://localhost/images/5.jpg',
    'sliderdescription' => 'a slider on rails is really nice',
    'sliderposition' => 5
    ),
    'six' => array(
    'slidertitle' => 'sixth slider',
    'sliderlocation' => 'http://localhost/images/6.jpg',
    'sliderdescription' => 'this is the sixth slider,like,really!',
    'sliderposition' => 6
    )
);
```

using data posted from a form.I have not sanitized by $_POST data since its just an example.

```
$clickedButton = $_POST['clickedButton'];
$sliderKey = $_POST['sliderKey'];
$sliderTitle = $_POST['sliderTitle'];
$sliderDescription = $_POST['sliderDescription'];
$sliderLocation = $_POST['sliderLocation'];
$sliderPosition = $_POST['sliderPosition'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM arr");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$data = $row['encoded_array'];
//echo $data.'<br/>'.'<br/>';
$unserialized = unserialize($data);
$unserialized[$sliderKey]["slidertitle"] = $sliderTitle;
$unserialized[$sliderKey]["sliderlocation"] = $sliderLocation;
$unserialized[$sliderKey]["sliderdescription"] = $sliderDescription;
$unserialized[$sliderKey]["sliderposition"] = $sliderPosition;
//print_r($unserialized);
$newSerialize = serialize($unserialized);
mysql_query("UPDATE arr SET encoded_array = '$newSerialize'");
```

when i `print_r $unserialized`,the data i have just posted is there,but is not committed to the database after i serialize.Is there something i am doing wrong?.

**EDIT:**

I have two records in my array and this is what i get before saving

```
a:2:{s:13:"5056d218631bc";a:4:{s:11:"slidertitle";s:5:"lorem";s:14:"sliderlocation";s:5:"ipsum";s:17:"sliderdescription";s:11:"hello world";s:14:"sliderposition";i:3;}s:13:"5056db269305c";a:4:{s:11:"slidertitle";s:1:"A";s:14:"sliderlocation";s:6:"RECORD";s:17:"sliderdescription";s:18:"WITH A DESCRIPTION";s:14:"sliderposition";s:1:"2";}}
```

Unserialized:

```
Array
(
    [5056d218631bc] => Array
        (
            [slidertitle] => lorem
            [sliderlocation] => ipsum
            [sliderdescription] => hello world
            [sliderposition] => 3
        )

    [5056db269305c] => Array
        (
            [slidertitle] => A
            [sliderlocation] => RECORD
            [sliderdescription] => WITH A DESCRIPTION
            [sliderposition] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: what do you get if you `var_dump($newSerialize);` before the DB insertion?

Comment: the data i have posted is there.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: before firing mysql_query , echo the update query its seems not putting $newSerialize vaiable value

Comment: @flapjack, regarding your last comment - no you have not! do: `$newSerialize = serialize($unserialized); print_r($newSerialize);` and add the output to your question. Like Jaitsu suggested!

Comment: Try mysql_query("UPDATE arr SET encoded_array = '" . $newSerialize . "'");

Comment: What's the `column-type` of: 'encoded_array' ?  You can use `mysql_error` to see if you get any error from your `update`.

Comment: I shall look into that,thanks.column-type is text,but that shouldn't be a problem.I am now thinking that jquery is calling the delete function after i save.I shall post updates.

Answer (score 0):

@alfasin @AdamGold @Poonam @Jaitsu I truly deserve every bit of rebuke for posting this,but the problem was that i was missing a break after the function that did the saving:

This is what  i had before

```
$x = $_POST['clickedButton'];

switch ($x)
{
case 'newSave':
  newSave();
  break;
case 'editSave':
  editSave();
  ;
case 'editDelete':
  editDelete();
  ;
  break;
default:
  echo "Some click";
}
```

This is what i have now that works

```
$x = $_POST['clickedButton'];
//echo $x;
switch ($x)
{
case 'newSave':
  newSave();
  break;
case 'editSave':
  editSave();
  ;
  break;
case 'editDelete':
  editDelete();
  ;
  break;
default:
  echo "Some click";
}
```

I thank you for your patience and contributions.